# Customizing the iOS permission dialog for push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios-permissions

When an iOS app attempts to register for push notifications for the first time, the system pops up a permissions dialog asking the user for permission to receive push notifications. Is it possible to customize the text of this dialog, to explain why these permissions are being sought?

Most permission dialog messages can be customized by putting in an `NS*UsageDescription` [Info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) key. For example the `NSCameraUsageDescription` key controls what dialog text to display when requesting access to the user's camera. But there does not appear to be such a key for push notifications.

Comment: I'd like to re-open this question. I remember reading somewhere that in iOS 7 you can customize the permission dialog, I can't remember where I read this now though. Can someone help?

Comment: I think the customization for permission dialogs (since iOS 6) only applies to other permission types, but for more details, you can read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158871/ios-custom-permission-alert-view-text/14161372#14161372

Comment: @DanielT. yes we can only for subtitle please see this think               https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: This is surprising, it would be relatively easy for Apple to allow the key in `InfoPlist.strings`. Or if there's no customization point for policy reasons, then Apple should localize it themselves like the other automatic dialogs and buttons (like "OK", "done", "cancel", etc).

Answer (score 55):

No, this is a system dialog which cannot be customized.

Comment: As a workaround, a separate dialog can be displayed prior to taking action that would show the system permissions dialog.

Comment: @David Foster  is it possible to change the permission dilog box (camera persmission) text to chineese ? how to do it have any idea?

Comment: @Ramesh 1. Yes, you can add whatever text you want as permission text in plist file, but for location service you can't, its system dialogue. 2. If app supports internalisation,  follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file

Answer (score 12):

One workaround that I have seen involves an app bringing up its own custom dialog explaining why it needs a permission. Then immediately afterwards the app requests the permission, bringing up the system dialog.

This may be suitable for convincing a user to accept the permission request in order to gain access to a feature, or to reject the request with the knowledge that the feature will not be available.

Comment: Yep, like in this example: https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you mean the text under title like this image

[image]

If yes, modify your `info.plist` file. Adding a new key `Privacy - User Notifications Usage Description`, this is also a Xcode inbuilt option, you can select from menu. Then type what ever text in value.

[image]

Here's request code in `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```swift
if UserDefaults.shared.isFirstLaunch {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
        if success {
            print("All set!")
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    UserDefaults.shared.isFirstLaunch = false
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @pors Hi, which iOS version are you using?

Comment: iOS 15.5 @Roger

Comment: @pors I've added my code sample in answer and set custom description to 'Hello pors', it seems working fine on iOS 15.5, could you show me more about your code? Screenshot: https://imgur.com/X9VAwlM

Comment: I work with Expo (React Native), but I'm able to add entries to info.plist

Comment: @pors Sorry, this answer is for native iOS app

Comment: Maybe add the Info.plist key so people trying to add this outside of Xcode can easily follow. It is `NSUserNotificationsUsageDescription`.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible, since you dont have any control on it whatsoever

Answer (score 4):

No you cant change system in built message.because you dont have any control to it.

Answer (score 1):

As Septronic pointed out, [at least as of macOS 12.3 / iOS 15.4](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708259), the body of the prompt to allow notifications can be customized using the not-really-documented `NSUserNotificationsUsageDescription` Info.plist key.

You can add a value for the key `Privacy - User Notifications Usage Description` to your app's `Info.plist` with the desired string. If you edit the XML Plist directly, use this

```
<key>NSUserNotificationsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your description goes here.</string>
```

Answer (score -1):

System dialog title cannot be customized. But you can customize description message underneath.

Comment: > But you can customize description -- How?

Comment: @DavidFoster I can't edit my post, but you can either add a value for this key `Privacy - User Notifications Usage Description` (if you open as property list), or this (if as source code): 

```
 <key>NSUserNotificationsUsageDescription</key>
 <string></string>
```