# iOS: Custom permission alert view text

Tags: ios, uialertview

Anyway to custom permission alert view like: Contacts, Photo Album, Push Notifications... before they get access, they will pop up an alert view like this:

[image]

How to custom Contacts, photo album, push notifications alert view text?

UPdate:

[image]

See the update image above, translate into english:

> "To seek for your family and friends, Path needs to transfer your
>   contacts to our server"

And click OK to get contacts access without any other access permission alert view pops up.

Comment: You cannot customize this alert boxes

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Under iOS 6 and above, these can be setup to show specific messages. Edit your Info.plist by adding a few new entries. The keys all begin with "Privacy - " (the raw keys are `NSxxxUsageDescription` where `xxx` is Contacts, Locations, Reminders, PhotoLibrary, or Calendards). The value is the text you wish to display to the user.

Comment: The list of keys are described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Search for UsageDescription to highlight all of them

Comment: but, we can't customize for push notification