# Is customized view for 'Contact Access Alert' possible?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uialertview, contacts

I have an app (iOS 6)that asks for contacts access upon sign up.
It has a custom view. That is it has a custom message along with it two buttons. On pressing `Allow`, it allows access to contacts. The other button is `Why?`, in which it explains why the permission is needed and the user can then allow. (There is no option to NOT Allow).

Now I'm porting this app to iOS. How will I change the permission alert view to my needs. Is it even Possible?

Closely Related: [iOS: Custom permission alert view text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158871/ios-custom-permission-alert-view-text)

Comment: is this permission alert of your application or any ios sdk or third party

Comment: its a UIAlertView item

Comment: can you share your code here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158871/ios-custom-permission-alert-view-text