# iOS Push Notification Custom Alert

Tags: ios, notifications, push, uialertcontroller

I am trying to enable push notifications in my iOS app. I wanted to create a custom alert to ask the user if they want to enable the notifications. Does apple allow this/possible to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [register](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW25) for notifications, a popup will appear asking the user for permission (unless he/she already gave permission before):

> The first time you call the registerUserNotificationSettings: method, iOS presents a dialog that asks the user for permission to present the types of notifications the app registered.

You *cannot* use a custom alert, like for instance when you ask for permission to use the user's location, or his/her contacts. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158871/ios-custom-permission-alert-view-text) has a nice [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) where you can find which permission alerts you *can* customize.

Comment: Can I customize the popup that appears?

Comment: Sorry - it seems I missed the word 'custom' in your question.

Comment: Just to confirm, I am stuck with the popup Apple gives me?

Comment: Yes. You could, of course, display your own popup, and if the user confirms, call `registerUserNotificationSettings:` afterwards. But that would display another popup (Apple's own) and this would be confusing to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I agree that this would be very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When you incorporate push notifications into the app - it automatically asks the user if they want to allow push notifications. There is no need for you to create your own custom alert.

Comment: I was thinking to include an image along with the popup but it seems like this isn't possible. thanks!