# QuickBlox push notification permission alert timing customisation

Tags: ios, quickblox

I just wanted to know whether it is possible to customise when the push notification permission alert is asked. We want to have a more clear prompt versus asking the moment the app launches.
As far as I konw QB framework forces it to be asked the moment the app launches and we can't modify that.

So is it possible to customise push notification permission alert timing for iOS?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to customise the alert, or want to  show that alert based  on some condition?

Comment: I think Its not possible, Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656775/ios-push-notification-custom-alert

Answer (score 0):

You get this prompt when you call the method

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
 #else
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
 #endif
```

Put this method at that place where you need to show prompt.