# iOS customize location request view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here's standard Location Service warning:

[image]

Can I customize that view (fonts, texts, background, etc.)?

UPD: found a way to change text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161372/5201559. Still looking for ways to change background.

UPD2: OK, I've thought about custom UIAlertView. But I'm not sure if I can allow or deny using location from custom, non-system view. How to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No you can't.**
This alert is shown by iOS itself and can't be altered by your app, unless we are talking about a jailbroken app.