# Can I customize default message for register notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to change default message for register notification .

Is this possible in iOS ?

[image: Default Alert pop up]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963711/customizing-the-ios-permission-dialog-for-push-notifications

Check this